# Save array after reorder with cdkDropList from Angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How can I save the new order of my array of reordered objects with Angular Material's `cdkDropList` even after a page refresh?

The reordering works fine but I can't save that new order. The array data comes from Firebase.

components.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.fs.getItemsDocument(this.id).subscribe( res => {
    this.items = res;
    this.itemsGroup = this.items.reduce((prev, { categoria, ...items }) => {
      const id = prev.findIndex((item) => item.categoria === categoria);
      id >= 0
        ? prev[id].items.push(items)
        : prev.push({categoria, items: [items]});
      return prev;
    }, []);
    console.log(this.itemsGroup);
  });
}

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.itemsGroup, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

components.html

```
 <div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
   <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let group of itemsGroup" cdkDrag>{{group.categoria}}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The order of the drag can be submitted to the back end

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: Let's say 1,10 switch places, pass these two ids to the back end, and the back end does the processing, and I don't know much about the back end so I don't know, but that's how development works, right

Answer (score 0):

use Local Storage or Session Storage to save data temporarily and get it back with an API call(**Local Storage has a 10MB**) limit.

You can have your code try to retrieve local storage values first if they exist.